# Update iframe with php page after ajax post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, iframe

```
$("form#update").submit(function() {
    var formData = $("form#update").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "graph.php",
            data: formData + "&criteria=" + critSelected,
            success: function(data){
                $('div.graph').fadeOut(function(){$('div.graph').html(data).fadeIn();});
            }
        });
    return false;
});
```

I have this script that responds to a form submit. graph.php will be a full html page I would like to display without loading the entire page again. Is there any way for me to change the source of an iframe on the same page as the form to graph.php (say it's inside the div 'graph')? I've tried placing $('iframe').attr('src', url); in the success function to no avail. Help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can post directly to iframe using form.target='frame name'
Than the result will be loaded in iframe automaticly

For example

```
<form method="POST" target="framename">...</form>
```

Comment: Yep, that's way easier. How would I create the form tag? I got the target to be the iframe and it updated it with graph.php, but it's displaying it as if the $_POST data didn't make it through.

Comment: @meburbo did you remove the AJAX?

Answer (score 1):

If I read what you've done correctly the reason it's not working is because you're trying to use url as a variable where it's the name of a property within ajax options. If you change your code to `$("iframe").attr("src", "graph.php");` it should work or set alternatively set the url variable.

Concept Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XcnMt/

Comment: And to be honest I think what you're looking for is in zim32's answer. If you want the forms page to be loaded in full within your page you don't need the AJAX stuff just post to the iframe.

Comment: Yeah, it is way better. Thanks for the help. Did you see my response to his answer? Any suggestions?